# CloudFlare - 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: file-upload, browser, cloudflare

I’m experiencing weird issue with file upload on server behind cloudflare. When I try to upload an image from browser (chrome & mozilla) I get this error “413 Request Entity Too Large - cloudflare” which means that the sent request is bigger than 100MB (as said in the docs) but actually the image size is 18MB.

When I send the same request from postman - it works!
I’m sending even bigger files from postman and all are being uploaded successfully.

What could be the problem?

Javascript

```
return request.post('/resource/image')
  .use(SuperagentPromisePlugin)
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer xxx')
  .attach('file', file)
  .then((response) => {
    //...
  });
```

Comment: Make sure the function that posts is setting the correct `enctype` of `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @Jules I am also getting the same error even though it's multipart/form-data for 98MB file but it works for less than that, and I am using a pro subscription.